# counterexample of restricted normal operator be normal

Tags: linear-algebra

let $V$ be a finite dimension complex vector space and $T$ a normal operator. I'm looking for an example that on a $T$-invariant subspace ,$T$ is $not$ normal,for I really can't prove it must be.Any advise? Thank you

Comment: Sorry but to me, this is a bit confusing. can you explain to me the steps of how you want to disprove the given statement? to my understanding, you want to prove that restriction of normal operator need not be a normal operator.

Comment: I think a normal matrix which is two-block upper triangular is hopefully to be a counterexample.it is necessarily not symmetric or the subspace be one dimension, for in these two cases the assertion is obviously right.

Comment: just like the matrix you gave, but i want a normal one..

Comment: Real 2x2 nor9mal matrix are symmetric or has form $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
-b & a
\end{bmatrix} $ [1](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/lectures/chapter6.pdf)

Comment: @KNilesh sorry i meant two-block uppertriangular not 2 dim..for example a 4×4 matrix with left-down 2×2 block be zero

Comment: @ysTuan: There is no such counterexample. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334869/when-is-the-restriction-of-a-normal-operator-not-normal?rq=1.